# XPath not working for screen scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am using Scrapy for a screen scraping project and am having problems with an XPath.

I am trying to get the 94,218 from the image below, but the XPaths and CSS I have used is not working.

[image]
It's from this page: https://fancy.com/things/280558613/I%27m-Fine-T-Shirt

I have tried multiple XPaths and CSS with Scrapy but everything is returning blank.

Here are some examples:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/aside/div[1]/div/div/a[2]/text()').extract()

response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar"]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]/text()').extract()

response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "fancyd_list", " " ))])'.extract()

response.xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/div[1]/div/div/a[2]/text()")
```

I've tried Firebug, Firepath, Chrome Dev Tools and different plugins but none of the XPaths or CSS seem to work.. can someone assist?

The code on the actual page is:

```
<a href="#" class="fancyd_list "/>
    6
</a>
```

Some of the XPaths work, but they contain no text, so it looks like this: `<a href="#" class="fancyd_list "/></a>`

I've also tried using BeautifulSoup, but it has the same problem:

```
print soup.find_all('a',class_='fancyd_list')
[<a class="fancyd_list " href="#"></a>, <a class="fancyd_list " href="#"></a>]
```

Thanks!

Comment: This type of parsing always drives me nuts. Use `beautiful soup` and I bet it will be trivial.

Comment: Hey thanks @RobertB will give that a crack, stayed away from it as I heard performance isn't the best

Comment: Hey @RobertB just tried BeautifulSoup and got same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the provided URL is returning HTML with a malformed `<a>` tag in the following:

```
<a href="#" class="fancyd_list "/>  # Malformed HTML, <a> tag closes here
    94,218
</a>
```

The first line here contains a `/` prior to the closing bracket, which by HTML standards indicates a completion of the `<a>` tag.  Since to Scrapy, the `<a>` element is done, you can't fetch the text outside of the tags.

The previous recommendation of using BeautifulSoup may be a good idea here, because it handles malformed HTML **much** better.

Another option you can have for this example would be to fix the HTML yourself, via something similar to:

```
new_body = re.sub(r'<a href="#" class="fancyd_list "/>', '<a href="#" class="fancyd_list ">', response.body)
response = response.replace(body=new_body)
```

You would then be able to select from the response via

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='frm']/div[@class='figure-button']/a[contains(@class, 'fancyd_list')]/text()").extract()
```

The reason I'm using "contains" is because the class name (for me) is appearing with a space at the end of it's name, and as such Scrapy's check of `"a[@class='fancyd_list']"` will fail, because `"fancyd_list" != "fancyd_list "`

Comment: You sir are a legend. Thank you!

Comment: I am a beginner with Python/Scrapy, and its returning:

`\n        -1\n`

Is there an easy way to extract the 1?

Comment: If it's returning a list, fetch the item you want out of the list and use `.strip()` to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace.  That should leave you with just the number (as a string).